# How to flip a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, math, rectangles, flip

Say I have a rectangle of the following form:

```
{ 
  x: number, 
  y: number, 
  w: number, 
  h: number, 
  a: number
}
```

Where `x` and `y` refer to its top left point, `w` refers to its width, `h` refers to its height, and `a` refers to its angle in rotation around its center origin.

How would one perform a horizontal flip on this data structure? That is, visually, it should change from:

[image]

to:

[image]

Is there a mathematical operation that yields this result?

Likewise, is there a similar operation that would yield a vertical flip of the same data structure?

Here's some code for drawing rotated rectangles:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function rotateCanvas(ctx, x, y, a) {
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(a);
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);
}

function drawRotatedRectangle(ctx, rX, rY, rW, rH, rA) {
  rotateCanvas(ctx, rX + rW / 2, rY + rH / 2, rA);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(rX, rY, rW, rH);
  ctx.stroke();
  rotateCanvas(ctx, rX + rW / 2, rY + rH / 2, -rA);
}

drawRotatedRectangle(context, 30, 30, 100, 50, 0.5);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247903/discussion-on-question-by-ryan-peschel-how-to-flip-a-rectangle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is literally just:

```
rectangle.angle = -rectangle.angle
```

This works for horizontal flips and vertical flips since they both yield the same result interestingly enough.